# Changing cell color based on value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, libreoffice, openoffice-calc

I have a libreoffice/excel spreadsheet that has thousands of rows in one column.  I would like to have the cell change color base on it's value.  How can this be done?

```
Example:
23   
42   
42
53
56
```

All rows with 42 would change cell color to blue

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use conditional formatting. Select the range and apply conditional formatting for equals operation. Available in the Home tab in excel 2007 and 2010